# Best RoR pattern for special instances of a subclass

Tags: mvc, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out the best way to "partially" use the validates_uniqueness_of validator for a particular case of problem.

Let's say I have a Book class with multiple comments, with the Comment class having a `belongs_to :book`. Now let's say I have certain comments which I consider notable, such as "most quotable" or "most famous" or whatever. To date, I would generally add a `most_quotable_comment_id` and a `most_famous_comment_id` foreign key to the Book class. But this gets unwieldy when you also have "most tweeted" and so on. Eventually your Book object has a ton of foreign keys. But assuming I only want one "most_*x*" for any given type (in other words, two comments can't equally be "most quotable"), it's the easiest mechanism to implement.

An alternative might be to define a bunch of values like `MOST_COMMENTED = 1` (etc) and then add a field such as `t.column :comments, :most_what, :integer`. So now I can extend this system however I want, just by adding more `MOST_x` values. This pre-supposes that one comment can't be "most quotable" and also "most famous", for the sake of argument.

So now I need to add a validator to make sure that for a given book, only one comment has `most_what == MOST_COMMENTED`. So that seems pretty straightforward:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :most_what, :scope => :book_id, :conditions => {where.not(:most_what => 0)}
```

The last bit to avoid the problem that most comments aren't most-anything! :)

So this all seems a bit clunky to me, and I'm wondering what are the opinions of using a mechanism like this over just adding all the foreign keys to the main class. For the record, I'm not actually talking about books and comments, so it is safe to assume that I'll never have a comment which scores in two categories.

As I said, I originally coded it with foreign keys and my own view is that if you're dealing with a "handful" of foreign keys, the original method is best, but eventually as you add more categories, the other method is preferred. But what's a "handful"? Two? Ten? Also, I'm curious about that second pattern and whether it's really *wholesome* (for want of a better word).